# how to open menu on screen touch in android

Tags: android, menu, touch-event, popupmenu

I am developing image related application. All images comes from web service and displays on fullscreen ImageView. when user touch any image(ImageView). bottom bar should automatically display's for 3 to 4 seconds. Bottom bar contains "save" button also after 3 to 4 second, it should automatically hide. Please help me..

Comment: i am trying to display transparent menu at top and bottom on Image Touch Event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a QuickAction in onClick event of images.

Here is a link: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

You can also use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) class to dismiss QuickAction after 3 seconds.